# How to change .NET framework for xamarin.plugin.filepicker

Tags: xamarin, plugins, nuget-package

hi while working on xamarin.forms app I am getting the following warning when i try to run my program and my app is not opening 
here is the warning 
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker 1.2.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

please help to resolve this issue

Comment: you need to change the target framework of YOUR project

Comment: I tried to change to .NETFramework version = v4.6.1 but the target framework v4.6.1 is not showing up in my  list even after installing it